# The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first react native

Tags: react-native

I want use Marker inside MapView. Every time I want to load I face this error . Any help would be appreciated.

I got some solutions. But didn't workout for my case.

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";

import MapView, { Polyline } from "react-native-maps";

<View style={StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject}>
  <MapView
    showsUserLocation //to show user current location when given access
    loadingEnabled //to show loading while map loading
    style={styles.map}
    initialRegion={{
      // latitude : 27.6937681,
      latitude,
      // longitude : 85.3216398,
      longitude,
      latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
      longitudeDelta: 0.0421
    }}
  >
    <>
      {locations &&
        locations.map((location, index) => {
          const {
            coords: { latitude, longitude }
          } = location;
          return (
            <Marker
              key={index}
              coordinate={{ latitude, longitude }}
              // onPress={this.onMarkerPress(location)}
            />
          );
        })}

      <Polyline strokeWidth={2} strokeColor="red" coordinates={coords} />
    </>
  </MapView>
</View>
```

I want to render Marker with no error.

Here are my dependencies used :

````
"dependencies": {
    "native-base": "^2.13.8",
    "react": "16.9.0",
    "react-native": "0.61.2",
    "react-native-maps": "git+https://git@github.com/react-native-community/react-native-maps.git"
}```
````

Comment: Can you try removing the React Fragment(<>.... </>) ?

Comment: Thankyou for your comment . But it didnt worked .(still getting same error)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I make it work like this :

```
<View style={StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject}>
                <MapView 
                    showsUserLocation //to show user current location when given access
                    loadingEnabled //to show loading while map loading
                    style={styles.map}
                    initialRegion={{
                        latitude,
                        longitude,
                        latitudeDelta : 0.0922,
                        longitudeDelta: 0.0421
                    }}
                >

                    <Polyline
                        strokeWidth={2}
                        strokeColor="red"
                        coordinates={coords}
                    />  

                    {

                        locations && locations.map((location, index) => {
                            const {
                                coords: { latitude, longitude }
                            } = location;

                            return (
                                <MapView.Marker
                                    key={index}
                                    coordinate={{ latitude, longitude }}
                                    title={location.name}
                                    description={location.address}

                                />
                            )
                        })
                    }

                </MapView>
            </View>
```

Happy Sharing & Coding.

Comment: what is the style of the map?